# takeWhile with subscribing to new Single each time

Tags: rx-java2

I have a data source `fun getData(page : Int) : Single<List<Data>>`.

I'd like to create a behaviour where I could subscribe to that source each time with *different parameters each time* until `conditionCheck()` returns `true`.

I imagine something like this:

```
getData(page)
  .doOnNext { page++ }
  .doOnNext { /* manipulate data */ }
  .takeWhile { conditionCheck() }
  .subscribe({
    print "Completed"
  })
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by _each time_? It sounds to me like you want to keep calling getData until some condition is met. How do the new params come about? Do you need the previous params to come up with new params, or do you just have a list of all of the params you'd like to try?

Comment: @michaelavila updated details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different way to think about it (pseudocode-ish):

```
initialPage = Observable.just(1);
futurePages = PublishSubject.create();

allPossiblePages = Observable.concat(initialPage, futurePages);

allPossibleData = allPossiblePages
  .map(page -> getData(page))
  .do(page -> futurePages.onNext(/* manipulate page data */));

dataYouWant = allPossibleData
  .filter(data -> conditionCheck(data))
  .takeFirst()
  .subscribe( /* data should be here */);
```

Maybe this isn't the best way to do this, someone will speak up if that's the case. I'm not a big fan of the line `.do(page -> futurePages.onNext ..)`, but something like this might work.

I put together an example that runs using rxjs (easiest to prototype/demo) here: https://plnkr.co/edit/uXE53ygo8REzpbMJdvsD

Comment: Yeah... I oversimplified params part. It's more than just `page`. It is more than just `page` and is updated `getData().onSuccess()` and thus can't be pregenerated.

Comment: But anyway, that helped a lot!

Comment: @martynas-jurkus edited, let me know if this is more useful (or not)